# Hierarchical Entity Framework Query Exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am attempting to build up a hierarchical collection using Entity Framework - see the below query - every member in a given company has a parent member - but when trying to execute this I get the following exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: The type
>   'Member' appears in two structurally
>   incompatible initializations within a
>   single LINQ to Entities query. A type
>   can be initialized in two places in
>   the same query, but only if the same
>   properties are set in both places and
>   those properties are set in the same
>   order.

If I remove the ParentMember assign it works - any ideas on what is going on?

```
        return from c in _Entities.Company
               where c.Deleted == false
                select new Member()
                {
                    Name = c.Name,
                    ParentMember = new Member() 
                    {
                        Name = c.ParentMember.Name
                    }
                };
```

Answer (score 12):

I haven't tried this, but the error message gives you a clue:  you're not setting the same properties in the same order in both places.

What happens if you try setting an ID property on the outer Member()?

Comment: I've just updated the code in the question to reflect the actual code - I have exactly the same properties being set in the same order with the exception of setting the ParentMember property of the ParentMember, if that makes sense.

Comment: Actually, you're still not setting all the same params:  the outer has Name and ParentMember, while you're only setting the Name for the inner.  Try assigning the property a null.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
return (from c in _Entities.Company
               where c.Deleted == false
                select new
                {
                    c.Name,
                    ParentMember = new
                    {
                        c.ParentMember.Name
                    }
                })
.AsEnumerable()
.Select(c=> new Member
                {
                    Name = c.Name,
                    ParentMember = new Member
                    {
                        Name = c.ParentMember.Name
                    }
                });
```

Comment: +1 This catch-22 situation just bit me, and this was the solution I came up with independently.  Less elegant than I was hoping, and a little wasteful, since we have to do double the object instantiation, but nonetheless effective.

Answer (score 1):

You will end up with a recursion of Member records when you try to retrieve the same fields in each one. You can't just make the last parent record equal to null.

I would retrieve what I could and then build up the record with further queries. Note that your Company entity will require a ParentId field or similar.

```
var members = 
  return from c in _Entities.Company
  select new Member()
  {
    Name = c.Name,
    ParentId = c.ParentId
  };
```

Now iterate and add in the parent records.

```
foreach (var member in members)
{
  member.ParentMember = new Member 
    {
      Name = _Entities.Company.First(c => c.Id == member.ParentId).Name
    };
}
```